# Generate Solana keypair in Python

Tags: javascript, python, solana

I have this code in JS:

> 

```js
import nacl from "tweetnacl";
import {binary_to_base58} from "base58-js";
import bip39 from "bip39";
import ed25519 from "ed25519-hd-key";

async function main() {
  const seed = await bip39.mnemonicToSeed(
      "main holiday sing female devote vacant foot cream drink lecture wage marble bread special logic follow rose fire morning invite fatal make office search");
  const seedBuffer = Buffer.from(seed).toString('hex');
  const path44Change = `m/44'/501'/0'/0'`;
  const derivedSeed = ed25519.derivePath(path44Change, seedBuffer).key;
  const keypair = nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(derivedSeed)
}

main();
```

Please, help me to create the same code in Python. I'm completely confused about the libraries. I work in Python 3.10.